# What does spring-web use to serialize/deserialize data object to json in HTTP call

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Spring/Springboot provides a good framework in order to develop web application

it is very easy to implement ReSTfull HTTP calls. In these calls, it is even possible to provide data-object such as

```
public class User {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    long getId() { return id; }
    long getName() { return name; }
    long setId(long id) { this.id = id; }
    long setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

this data-object is serialized/deserialized to JSON automatically by the framework **without writing any line of code**

I would like to know what is the code/module used for that "automatic JSON serialization" and whether it is possible to reuse it for a completely different purpose?

Thanks for help

Comment: RTF(lippin)M [com.fasterxml.jackson](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/dependency-versions.html)

Answer (score 2):

By default, spring will use Jackson for both serialized/deserialized.

A quick way to verify this would be by using:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

From there you can see what dependancies are being pulled in by spring.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer by Todoy, Spring uses Jackson to serialize/deserialize java objects.

You can use Jackson without using it with Spring.  There are other java libraries that you can use for the same purpose (e.g. [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)) in case you want to explore other option.

Jackson Documentation
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs

Cheers,
Karl